# Retrieve data from a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this String which is coming from form:

```
   String tmp = "Reason: decision=deny&denyReason=1&denyReasonSubcategory=PoorQuality&subCategoryComments=testsubCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=denyReasonSubcategory=ReviewAgainsubCategoryComments=hellosubCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryComments=subCategoryCommen=&subCategoryComments=&subCategoryComments=&subCategoryComments=&subCategoryComments=";
```

From the above string I need to retrieve:

```
 denyReason=1
 denyReasonSubcategory=PoorQuality  subCategoryComments=test
 denyReasonSubcategory=ReviewAgain   subCategoryComments=hello
```

I need to save them as below:

deny Reason in an array, so i can find corresponding value.

Rest as:
Poor Quality :test; Review Again:hello

I have tried following:

```
          for (String word : tmp.split("\\&+")){
           if (word.contains("declineReason")){
                System.out.println(word.indexOf("declineReason"));
            // coming as 0
           }
          if (word.contains("declineReasonSubcategory")){
                System.out.println("helloo");
          }
          if (word.contains("subCategoryComments")){
                System.out.println("hii");
          } 
         }
        }
```

Honestly, it's been long since I work on string like this and just little lost on how to get the data.

Comment: First, why do you look for `declineReason` when there is no one in the data string ? Do you mean `denyReason` ? You should reword your question, it is not clear what you want.

Comment: Agree with I agree with @PeterMmm.. but it looks like you just need to do some string parsing. However, why do you have to store data like that in a string? Can't use you use another datatype like a map?

Comment: It looks like inbound URL query parameters. Anyway, I'd use a StringTokenizer  with `&`, then on each token, use another tokenizer on `=`. From there, process the results as you go (print out something if a token is present) or store them in a map.

Comment: It looks like some '&' are missing in the original string above, such as after 'test'.  That  might be causing you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Scanner to extract the values.
One scanner to extract the pairs.
Another scanner to extract the values of the pair.

See:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String tmp = "Reason: decision=deny&denyReason=1&denyReasonSubcategory=PoorQuality&subCategoryComments=testsubCategory";
      Scanner s = new Scanner(tmp).useDelimiter("\\&");
      while(s.hasNext()){
         Scanner s2 = new Scanner(s.next()).useDelimiter("=");
         System.out.println(s2.next() + ":" + s2.next());
      }
    }
}
```